# How to get the app list as displayed in Finder "Open in app" dialog for target file format (or file)?

Tags: swift, macos, finder, file-association

I need to get list of the apps which compatible with a specific file format ( the same as displayed in Open With in Finder for a specific file).

At first tried function "LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType" but in return not all apps ( often completely empty list). Programs appear in this list only if at least once in Finder make them the default for the file format.

Then I tried to get info about file associations formats from Info.plist of applications (using "CFBundleDocumentTypes" key). But for example for "png" I get only Browsers & no applications as Sketch, Skitch,Photoshop and etc.

Maybe I missing something...Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType()` should work. What roles mask are you passing? Have you tried `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()`?

Comment: @KenThomases
Roles mask -All (`LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType("public.html" as CFString, LSRolesMask.all`) .
I tried `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()` but get a nil ( maybe I use it incorrectly). 
`let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "file:///Users/xxx/Desktop/public.html")
        let CFUrl = url as CFURL
        print(LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(CFUrl,LSRolesMask.all)?.takeRetainedValue()`

First of all I interested in a variant for the file format.

Comment: If you need to start from a type and not a file of that type, it may be that `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType()` only returns apps which declare that content type specifically, while `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()` returns apps which declare that type and the types it conforms to. You could manually use `UTTypeCopyDeclaration()` and check the `kUTTypeConformsToKey` value to walk the chain. It seems you should stop at `public.data`, `public.content` and `public.item`, since those don't seem to add apps the Finder lists.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because your path was invalid:

```
// don't include file://
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "file:///Users/xxx/Desktop/public.html")
```

This works for me:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/xxx/Desktop/public.html") as CFURL

if let applicationURLs = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(url, .all)?.takeRetainedValue() {
    print(applicationURLs)
}
```

Comment: Just a note, this is already deprecated, NSWorkspace.shared.urlsForApplications can be used instead.